# Using map on an object in useState

Tags: reactjs

I created a person object in my useState, but I'm having trouble in using the `map` function on the person object. Any help is appreciated.

```js
 const [person, setPerson] = useState({
    name: "Nick",
    age: 30,
    showPersons: true,
  });
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `Map` only works on arrays in Js. You have declared and object with `{}`

Comment: Of course, problem now solved, thanks!

Comment: Should I add it as an answer, so it can help someone in the future?

Answer (score 0):

`map()` only works on arrays in Js. You have declared an object with `{}`.

Answer (score 0):

[Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) is an array method that only operates on arrays. `person` is an object though, so you would need to convert it to an array first.

Array of values ([Object.values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values)):

```
Object.values(person); // ["Nick", 30, true]
```

Array of key-value pairs ([Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)):

```
Object.entries(person); // [["name", "Nick"], ["age", 30], ["showPersons", true]]
```

For completionist's sake there is also an array of keys ([Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)), but this might be as useful:

```
Object.keys(person); // ["name", "age", "showPersons"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Map only works on arrays in Js. Object was declared with {}

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35705834)